# A problem in my code where it extends the list but not how I want it to

Tags: python, arrays, function

```
import os
import time 

os.system('clear')



null = ['strawberry', 'oranges', 'bananas', 'mangoes', 'grapes', 'apples']

def add(ml, KWS):
  ml = int(ml)
  KWS = str(KWS)
  null.insert(int(ml), str(KWS))

def sub(uy):
  uy = str(uy)
  null.remove(uy)

def extendo(kac):
  kac = str(kac)
  null.extend(kac)

print(null)

time.sleep(1)

i = 0

while i < len(null):
  i = i + 1
  if i == len(null): 
    print("This list has: ", str(i), " amount of values in this list.")

userinput = input("""Would you like to do:

a. Add something
b. Remove something
c. change range of list
d. more options
""")


if userinput == "a":
  num = input("Please state index number you would like to insert your value into.")
  choice = input("""Please enter the string you would like to add inside the list.""")
  x = add(num, choice)

if userinput == "b":
  xd = str(input("Please state as a string or integer what you would like clear from the list"))
  jj = sub(xd)
```

here is the problem

```
if userinput == "c":
  wtf = input("""Ok, what list would you like to create to extend the list?""")
  sus = extendo(wtf)
```

above this is a functions thing I created where if the user wants to extend the list, they would need to type in the string of text that they would like to integrate into the list.

For example, if I put pineapple to extend the list with, this is the result:

```
['strawberry', 'oranges', 'bananas', 'mangoes', 'grapes', 'apples', ' ', 'p', 'i', 'n', 'e', 'a', 'p', 'p', 'l', 'e', 's']
```

how do I fix that?

```
time.sleep(1)

print(null)
print("Review any changes.")
```

Comment: use `append` instead of `extend`. `extend` is for extending a list with another list. `append` is for appending one item to a list.